# how to Get all Images from any WebPage (in iphone)

Tags: iphone

Can anyone plese help me in this question,i m trying this but not getting any suitable answer ,i m a beginner to iphone.
in my app i m using a scroll view which will show all images of a given webpage.
my question is : how to Get all Images from any WebPage (in iphone)

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Ask yourself the question "how would I get all images from any web page not specifically on the iPhone?".

Comment: maybe this could help: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this tutorial of ray wenderlich has exactly what you need:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

You will handle ASIHTTP and grand central dispatcher to do what you need.

I hope it helps

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota you can mark this answer as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left - this is the best way to thank Julian.